# get the autogenerated ids of fixtures in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, minitest, fixtures

I have created some fixtures without ID in my rails 4.2 application. Since I relay on the ids in the url, I need a way to retrieve the autogenerated IDs in the database in the minitest files.

Remark: I am not using explicit ids in the fixtures. I am using this format:

```
student:
  name: Reginald_the_Pirate
  age: 14
```

In my controller I want something like:

```
get: :student, student_id: "?"
```

Answer (score 2):

```
student = students(:student)
get :student, :student_id => student.id
```

Answer (score 0):

this is the response. It is easier than what expected:

```
students(:Reginald_the_Pirate).id
```